# How do I blend/average N amount of frames as opposed to only 2?

Tags: ffmpeg

To average two frames in FFmpeg, one can use something like "tblend=all_mode=average,framestep=2". However, this only supports blending two frames at a time. Daisy chaining them only allows you to blend 2^N frames. What if I want to blend 3 frames, 5 frames, 6, 7, 9, and so on?

For my project in particular, I need to average 5 video frames into one. The source footage is 120fps, so this conversion would effectively reduce the framerate to 24. With tblend, this just won't be possible. How else can I go about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the tmix filter, available since ffmpeg v4.1

Basic syntax is

```
tmix=frames=5:weights="1 1 1 1 1",select='not(mod(n\,5))'
```

The tmix blends each frame with 4 following frames. The select filter then keeps only the first out of every 5 frames.

See [docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tmix).

Comment: I need a lighten-only filter, not average... it seems tmix wants to weight frames, which won't accomplish lighten-only.  And in my case I'm trying to do 100 frames at a time.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can apply `tblend` as many times as needed.